# VS2015 Cordova apps BLDErr_Build_NodeMissing

Tags: node.js, cordova, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to develop a cordova application using vs2015.I am new to vs2015 corodova application.I have been using the node.js and ionic cli to develop hybrid application.My system is Windows 8.1x64 bit.

After creating a sample vs2015 cordova application while running ,I got an error
"Severity Code  Description Project
File Line
Error BLDErr_Build_NodeMissing
Path to Node.js executable could not be determined. Please check that Node.js has been installed".

I have set the path variable for node js and npm in enviorment variable section.

Please help and 
Thanks in advance

Ajeesh13

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't look at environment variables to find node.js. It looks in certain registry settings and known file locations. It's interesting that it can't find it even though it's installed. Did you install it as a different user? Did you put it in a non-default location?

Comment: Try running VS in Administrative mode, helped for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue once I had installed Node 4.1 to a different path (other than default C:\ ). Reinstalling Node to default path and clearing the Cordova Cache fixed it for me. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Running VS'15 in Administrative mode (*Right click -> Shift + Right Click on Vs 2015 -> Run as Administrator*) ,solved the problem for me.

Re-installing [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) alone didn't solve the problem for me.